# Javascript ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID error

Tags: javascript, ssl

I have a problem when I try to call a service from the following script:

```
function campMasiva(array, ip, token, tipo, idcampana) {
        $.getJSON('https://' + ip + '/host/api_campaing.php?token=' + token + '&amp;action=' + array + '&amp;type_campaing=' + tipo + '&amp;campaing=' + idcampana, function (res)
                {                        
                    res = JSON.stringify(res);
                    var status = JSON.parse(res);
                });
    }
```

But I don't know how to inactivate the ssl verification.

Comment: Use an hostname in your HTTPS URL, not an IP address.

Comment: can you call the request without https?

Comment: I cant call without https because the service is defined with https.

Comment: I try:
`function campMasiva(array, ip, token, tipo, idcampana) {
            $.getJSON('https://' + ip + '/host/api_campaing.php?token=' + token + '&amp;action=' + array + '&amp;type_campaing=' + tipo + '&amp;campaing=' + idcampana, function (res)
                    {       
                        res = JSON.stringify({verify_peer:false, verify_peer_name:false});
                        var status = JSON.parse(res);
                    });
        }`

Comment: also:
`function campMasiva(array, ip, token, tipo, idcampana) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'https://' + ip + '/host/api_campaing.php?token=' + token + '&amp;action=' + array + '&amp;type_campaing=' + tipo + '&amp;campaing=' + idcampana,
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                rejectUnauthorized: false, 
                requestCert: false,
                agent: false, 
                verify_peer:false,
                verify_peer_name:false
            });

            &nbsp;
        }`

Comment: function campMasiva(array, ip, token, tipo, idcampana) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'https://' + ip + '/ipdialbox/api_campaing.php?token=' + token + '&amp;action=' + array + '&amp;type_campaing=' + tipo + '&amp;campaing=' + idcampana,
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                ssl:{verify_peer:false,verify_peer_name:false},
                rejectUnauthorized: false
            });

            &nbsp;
        }